# How do I remove `MutexGuard` around a value?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use ndarray as an asynchronous process to do linear algebra and such.
I used Rust's tokio and ndarray to create the following code.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use futures::future::join_all;

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db = Arc::new(Mutex::new(array![0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]));
    let mut handels = vec![];

    for i in 0..8 {
        let db = db.clone();
        let unchange_array = unchange_array.clone();
        handels.push(tokio::spawn(async move{
            print(i, db).await;
        }));
    }
    join_all(handels).await;
    let array = Arc::try_unwrap(db).unwrap();
    let array = array.lock().unwrap();
    print_type_of(&array);  // -> std::sync::mutex::MutexGuard<ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<u32>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>

}

async fn print(i: u32, db: Arc<Mutex<Array1<u32>>>) {
    let unchange = unchange.to_owned();
    let mut tmp = 0;
    // time-consuming process
    for k in 0..100000000 {
        tmp = k; 
    }
    tmp += i;
    let mut db = db.lock().unwrap();
    db.fill(i);
    println!("{:?}", unchange);
    print_type_of(&db);
}
```

I would like to change the data `std::sync::mutex::MutexGuard<ndarray::ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<u32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`
to `ndarray::ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<u32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? `MutexGuard` acts as a mutable reference and -- as its name notes -- guards the locking of the mutex, why do you care that it exists? Also... Also [use Mutex::into_inner](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.into_inner) instead of locking the mutex?

Comment: A Mutex uses locks to force one mutation at a time. A MutexGuard is essentially still a pointer, whereas an owned value would live on the stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. That's the whole point of `MutexGuard`: if you could take the data out of the `MutexGuard`, then you would be able to make a reference that can be accessed without locking the mutex, defeating the whole purpose of having a mutex in the first place.

Depending on what you *really* want to do, one of the following solutions might apply to you:

- Most of the time, you don't need to take the data out of the mutex: `MutexGuard<T>` implements `Deref<Target=T>` and `DerefMut<Target=T>`, so you can use the `MutexGuard` everywhere you would use a `&T` or a `&mut T`. Note that if you change your code to call `print_type_of(&*array)` instead of `print_type_of(&array)`, it [will print the inner type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66a933b6b97b73cbb760277e8e208e82).
- If you really need to, you can take the data out of the `Mutex` itself (but not the `MutexGuard`) with [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.into_inner), which consumes the mutex, ensuring that no one else can ever access it:

```
let array = Arc::try_unwrap(db).unwrap();
let array = array.into_inner().unwrap();
print_type_of(&array);  // -> ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<u32>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 1]>>
```